# web2py how to use db.current in a new thread?

Tags: web2py

```
    from gluon import current
import multiprocessing
def ip():
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=t,args=("hello",current.db))
p.start()
p.join()
print "start"
def t(arg1,arg2):
print "sub start %s"%arg1
print arg2.account.count()
```

It report errors thread.__local

How to use the current in a new thread? (i want to use the db to save date and session)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for you problem is because the `current` object isn't thread safe and shouldn't be used like that.

> For this reasons they are placed into a container called current,
>   which is a thread local object. [Check the docs](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Sharing-the-global-scope-with-modules-using-the-current-object)

If you want to access your database from another thread, you should pass your database object directly. I've done it before, and never had any problems accessing it from another thread.